# Calculating the differences between similar strings

Tags: r, datetime, difference, calculation

I have this data frame:

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Date_Time_GMT_3     LoggerID_SiteCode        value month  year   day time     
  <dttm>              <chr>                    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int> <Period> 
1 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X20819740_X3WR_S_Statio~  19.9 Aug    2021     1 12H 0M 0S
2 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare  19.3 Aug    2021     1 12H 0M 0S
3 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X20676906_X1WR_S_Statio~  18.8 Aug    2021     1 1H 45M 0S
4 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X21092863_X1WR_U_Compare  NA   Aug    2021     1 1H 45M 0S
5 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X20817726_14WR_S_Statio~  19.9 Aug    2021     1 2H 15M 0S
6 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X21092877_14WR_U_Compare  19.3 Aug    2021     1 2H 15M 0S
7 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X20819740_X3WR_S_Statio~  17.2 Sept   2021     1 1H 45M 0S
8 2021-08-01 12:00:00 X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare  17.0 Sept   2021     1 1H 45M 0S
```

My personal data frame is quite a bit bigger, the code above only shows the first couple rows.

I am trying to calculate the difference in values for `LoggerID_SiteCode` strings that contain the same `SiteCode`, for example when they both contain `X3WR` and therefore calculating the difference between `X20819740_X3WR_S_Stationary` and `X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare`. But it's important that when I calculate the difference between these 2 values, they are values that are occurring at the same date/time. Does anyone know how to do this?

**Data**

```
df = structure(list(Date_Time_GMT_3 = structure
                    (list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(12L, 12L, 
                      12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(7L, 
                      7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), year = c(121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121, 121, 121), 
                      wday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), yday = c(212L, 212L, 212L, 
                      212L, 212L, 212L, 212L, 212L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", 
                      "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                      NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), tzone = "EST", class = c("POSIXlt", 
                      "POSIXt")), LoggerID_SiteCode = c("X20819740_X3WR_S_Stationary", 
                      "X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare", "X20676906_X1WR_S_Stationary", "X21092863_X1WR_U_Compare", 
                      "X20817726_14WR_S_Stationary", "X21092877_14WR_U_Compare", 
                      "X20819740_X3WR_S_Stationary", "X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare"), value = c(19.948, 
                      19.321, 18.806, NA, 19.948, 19.300, 17.201, 17.012), month = c("Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
                      "Aug", "Aug", "Sept", "Sept"), year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), 
                      day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = new("Period", .Data = c(0, 
                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                        year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(12, 12, 
                        1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), minute = c(0, 0, 45, 45, 15, 15, 45, 45))), row.names = c(NA, 
                        -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `substr`. If you don't want NA to appear, add `na.rm = T` to the `diff` function.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(month, year, day, time,
           SiteCode = substr(LoggerID_SiteCode, 11, 14)) %>% 
  summarise(diff = diff(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   month, year, day, time [4]
  month  year   day time      SiteCode   diff
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <Period>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Aug    2021     1 1H 45M 0S X1WR     NA    
2 Aug    2021     1 2H 15M 0S 14WR     -0.648
3 Aug    2021     1 12H 0M 0S X3WR     -0.627
4 Sept   2021     1 1H 45M 0S X3WR     -0.189
```

Comment: hmm this works for the smaller data frame that I shared but not the larger one. I think it might have something to do with the fact that my larger data frame has multiple ```LoggerID_SiteCode```'s that occur on the same date/time

Comment: Then by what do those multiple SiteCode differ? you should be able to add more grouping variables to do it.

Comment: I see what happened. My time is not in military time, so it's trying to calculate the difference twice in 1 day because I have 1:00am and 1:00pm. Thanks for your help